# What is the effective way to store and retrieve the image feature?

Tags: python, image-processing, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction, faiss

I am a beginner in computer vision, my goal is to extract K-nearest neighbours for an image, I had a look at Annoy, Faiss, NMSLIB algorithms and decided to use Faiss for image similarity. I have a large dataset to check for the nearest neighbours. I am currently using faiss.IndexFlatIP, Since it is a brute force approach, it provides good results at the cost of time.

**Questions**:

1. Instead of brute force approach, is there any other way we can do this with good results?
2. Currently I am using pickle to save the large extracted features, is there any other way we can store and retrieve those features effectively?
3. I am currently using SIFT for feature extraction, whether CNN model will outperform this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Milvus is an open-source vector database built to power embedding similarity search and AI applications.(integrated Faiss/annoy/hnsw)
Compared to faiss, it's easy to manage embeddings with milvus

https://milvus.io/

https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a [managed faiss solution](https://www.pinecone.io/managed-faiss/) which supports feature retrieval.